# Finding a minimal polynomial with a modified root

Tags: polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Suppose you have a real number $x$. Given that its minimal polynomial is, say, $P(x)$, is there a simple way that you can find the minimal polynomial when $x$ is modified? For example, what the minimal polynomial of $x+\sqrt{2}$ is?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What is the definition you're using for the minimal polynomial of a number $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The definition of a minimal polynomial I'm using is the polynomial of the lowest degree possible, where all coefficients are integers.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to find the minimal polynomial of $y=p(x)/q(x)$, where $p,q$ are polynomials with rational coefficients. Then the minimal polynomial of $y$ is (a factor of) the resultant eliminating $x$ of $P(x)=0$ and $yq(x)-p(x)=0$; getting integers is a matter of multiplication.

In the case of non-rational coefficients, the second argument of the resultant will involve higher degrees of $y$, but the idea is still the same. For $y=x+\sqrt2$, the second polynomial will be $y^2-2xy+x^2-2=0$.